# Bitwise & (AND)

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a wrapper function to MD5 hashing that restricts the input and output size of MD5 to 20 bit. (all exceeding output bits are thrown away).
How can this be done?

Comment: 24bits -> 20 bits implies you have to discard some information.  What is the rule that governs this?

Comment: What do you mean by "24 bit string"? Can you show an example?

Comment: @JimGarrison something like Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC) would require this kind of bit shifting . Might be other scenarios too.

Comment: You are using the word `String` probably loosly here but is getting taken are `java.lang.String` you might want to take the word `String` out.

Comment: @Shahzeb There is no 'shifting' mentioned in the question, and CRCs don't require transforming 24 bits to 20.

Comment: @EJP yes you are right on both accounts but to me it seemed like OP is after bit shifting . Ofcourse that's not clearly stated and I might well be wrong.

Comment: @AhmetYildirim Please edit your post to specify what you want to do.  Provide some examples of 24-bit inputs and the corresponding 20-bit outputs, along with the rule for performing the conversion.  Do you want to take the low-order (right-most) 20 bits? High-order 20 bits (left-most)? Some form of hashing?

Comment: Is MD5 input literally an String ??? -> MD5function(String input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value20Bits = value24Bits & 0xfffff;`? or some other mask?

Comment: There's an implicit assumption that the high-order 4 bits are to be discarded.  The OP hasn't specified what transformation is needed.